# what is the difference of Address space segment and Program memory segment in memory?

Tags: c, memory

1、there are sections like .text, .data, .bss etc in a executable file.
2、and there are also Program memory segment(code,initialized data, uninitialized data(BSS),heap,stack)which can be mapped from sections in executable file.

Above each, i can understand what it is,section is placed in disk while segment is placed in memory while the program is loaded. and when the program begins to run, Initialized data,BSS,Heap segment are all placed into Data segment, the following table describes more details:

This table is referenced from http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleW.html Table w.6:

[image: Table w.6]
my question is what is the difference of **Address space segment** and  **Program memory segment** in memory?

Comment: Hmm, that's not really a reliable (or reputable?) source.

Answer (score 1):

They're just different ways of referring to the same segments in memory..

- The 'Code' - or 'Text' - segment is loaded from the .text section of the executable file, and the memory pages into which this is loaded are marked executable.
- The 'Data' portion of the program address space contains 3 different logical sections:

  - Initialised data (loaded from the .data section of the executable file)
  - Uninitialised data - for which the .bss section of the executable records a size to be allocated, but no actual content (after all, it's uninitialised!)
  - And dynamically allocated data (the heap) - which is allocated as the program runs, and therefore doesn't have, or need, a matching section in the executable
    Memory pages for all of these data section will be read/write, and theoretically non-executable too.
- The 'Stack' portion - in essence similar to a data-type section, but with special meaning/purpose in the execution of the program. Also not backed by a section in the executable file.

The exact way in which these sections/segments are dealt with is obviously implementation specific - with the layout of the file depending on the specific executable format and linker used , and the layout of the program in memory again depends on the executable format utilised and the OS loader. As an example of this, according to this discussion of the PE file format - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx - one of the Borland linkers used to drop the .bss section from the executable file and instead combine it with the .data section - I suspect there are many examples of similar variabilities depending on the different flavors of OS/Linkers/Executable formats used.

Answer (score 0):

In the memory no difference.

But, usually they have separated caches. Also, in the virtual memory table, code segment is marked as such, so trying to execute something that is not code segment will crash the program.

Note that this actually vary from platform to platform.

Comment: Separate caches => maybe cannot change instructions. Everything varies by platform.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Excuse me, I did not get what you said by "maybe cannot change instructions"